# Single_cat_title > multiple_cat_title

Tags: wordpress

I got a custom post type with custom categories (custom taxonomy).

Now I want to create a page where posts from two categories are listed, but I don't get it to work.

The standard function used to list the current category is:

```
<?php echo single_cat_title(); ?>
```

This works great when the page is: domain.com/custom-taxonomy/category-name/

But when the domain is: domain.com/custom-taxonomy/category-name+another-category-name/ the category shown will be "category-name".

When I use:

```
<?php wp_list_categories(); ?>
```

It will list all categories that has posts.

Is there a function that would do just:

```
multiple_cat_title();
```

Some extra info:
The custom post type is called projects
The custom taxonomies are: projectcategory and projectstatus
I want to show "Design & Develop" when you visit the url:

```
domain.com/projectcategory/design+develop/
```

Regards!

Comment: Are you looking to just show all the categories, or just the ones for the current page?

Comment: What is the slug for your custom post type? Also, what is the taxonomy name and category slug for your two categories?

Comment: I'm trying to show the categories in the url.

Comment: You're talking about using multiple query vars in the url to display posts from multiple categories? You can try to set up rewrite rules to accomplish this, which would not be easy or simple, but i'd reccomend creating pages and using page templates to quickly accomplish this. A wp_query() in a page template could easily display posts from two categories, and it would also be easy to set up the URL's for a page and their parents. However automatically doing the same thing through rewrite rules would be much more difficult. You need to clarify exactly which way you'd want to accomplish it.

Comment: Thanks Mastrianni, but that's not an option. The content displayed on taxonomy-projectcategory.php is very flexible. Sometimes it shows posts with two "projectcategories", and sometimes with just one, or even three.